# The PersistentVolume is invalid: spec: Required value: must specify a volume type

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-rook, rook-storage

I'm trying to create a Persistent Volume on top of/based off of an existing Storage Class Name. Then I want to attach the PVC to it; so that they are bound. Running the code below, will give me the "sftp-pv-claim" I want, but it is not bound to my PV ("sftp-pv-storage"). It's status is "pending".

The error message I receive is: "The PersistentVolume "sftp-pv-storage" is invalid: spec: Required value: must specify a volume type".  If anyone can point me in the right direction as to why I'm getting the error message, it'd be much appreciated.

**Specs:**

I'm creating the PV and PVC using a helm chart.

I'm using the Rancher UI to see if they are bound or not and if the PV is generated.

The storage I'm using is Ceph with Rook (to allow for dynamic provisioning of PVs).

**Error:**

The error message I receive is: "The PersistentVolume "sftp-pv-storage" is invalid: spec: Required value: must specify a volume type".

**Attempts:**

I've tried using claimRef and matchLabels to no avail.

I've added "volumetype: none" to my PV specs.

If I add "hostPath: path: "/mnt/data"" as a spec to the PV, it will show up as an Available PV (with a local node path), but my PVC is not bonded to it. (Also, for deployment purposes I don't want to use hostPath.

```
## Create Persistent Storage for SFTP
## Ref: https://www.cloudtechnologyexperts.com/kubernetes-persistent-volume-with-rook/

kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: sftp-pv-storage
  labels:
    type: local
    name: sftp-pv-storage
spec:
  storageClassName: rook-ceph-block
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  allowVolumeExpansion: true
  volumetype: none

---
## Create Claim (links user to PV)
##  ==> If pod is created, need to automatically create PVC for user (without their input)

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: sftp-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: sftp-pv-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

Answer (score 4):

**The PersistentVolume "sftp-pv-storage" is invalid: spec: Requiredvalue: must specify a volume type.**

In PV manifest you must provide type of volume. List of all supported types are described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes). 
As you are using `Ceph` I assume you will use  `CephFS`.

> A cephfs volume allows an existing CephFS volume to be mounted into
>   your Pod. Unlike emptyDir, which is erased when a Pod is removed, the
>   contents of a cephfs volume are preserved and the volume is merely
>   unmounted. This means that a CephFS volume can be pre-populated with
>   data, and that data can be “handed off” between Pods. CephFS can be
>   mounted by multiple writers simultaneously.

Example of `CephFS` you can find in [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/volumes/cephfs).

**If I add "hostPath: path: "/mnt/data"" as a spec to the PV, it will show up as an Available PV (with a local node path), but my PVC is not bonded to it.**

If you will check [Official Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class-1) about `storageClassName`.

> A claim can request a particular class by specifying the name of a
>   StorageClass using the attribute storageClassName. Only PVs of the
>   requested class, ones with the same storageClassName as the PVC, can
>   be bound to the PVC.

`storageClassName` of your `PV` and `PVC` are different.

PV:

```
spec:
  storageClassName: rook-ceph-block
```

PVC:

```
spec:
  storageClassName: sftp-pv-storage
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score -1):

You did not specify the "hostPath:" in your PersistentVolume
Add it and the error should be resolved. See sample below

[image: hostPath]